# Regular expression to parse Java package and class name from cannonical class name

Tags: java, regex

I'm configuring a log parsing system (Logstash) that uses Regular expressions to parse logs. I'm trying to parse out a package name and class name from a canonical (i.e. fully qualified) Java class name, but I can't get it quite right.

Here are some sample inputs

1. `UnpackagedClass`
2. `somepackage.SomeClass`
3. `java.lang.Object`
4. `java.util.function.Function`

Expected output (capture groups):

1. (empty string), `UnpackagedClass`
2. `somepackage`, `SomeClass`
3. `java.lang`, `Object`
4. `java.util.function`, `Function`

Here is what I tried: `((?:(?:X)\.)*)((?:X))`, where `X` is `[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*`, the regex for a Java identifier. Fully expanded, it's: `((?:(?:[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*)\.)*)((?:[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*))`. It's close, but there are trailing periods after the package names, that get captured as part of the package names:

1. (empty string), `UnpackagedClass`
2. `somepackage.`, `SomeClass`
3. `java.lang.`, `Object`
4. `java.util.function.`, `Function`

Any suggestions on how I can improve this? Here's [a RegExr playground](https://regexr.com/3seqg) to help you .

Comment: @Andreas Ding ding ding! Write up an answer and collect your internet points :)

Comment: If you're using Java regular expressions, you can use `"\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*"` to match any valid Java identifier.

Comment: Please note: your examples are all fine, but omitting many special cases such as correct names of anonymous inner classes. It probably depends what exactly gets logged, but option space goes way beyond the requirements you stated here.

Comment: @GhostCat Oooof, great catch, I did complete forget about anon classes!

Comment: How about `java.util.Map.Entry` and likes?

Comment: @lexicore I thought about that after GhostCat's comment. I'm not too concerned about it, because 1) Although we use lots of lambdas, I don't think we have any named inner classes, certainly not any that we log from, and 2) This info is for human consumption during debugging. The entire qualified name is stored intact and is indexed for searching, so we can just resort to consulting it if we're looking for a named inner class. It's okay if this parsing is just "best effort"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use: `(?:(X(?:\.X)*)\.)?(X)`

It will have package name in group 1 (`null` if unnamed), and class name in group 2.

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mTWpYK/1) for demo.